# Localization in Prism WPF App

Tags: localization, prism, cal

I'm looking for the best way to localize a Prism 2 WPF app that might have several modules ported to Silverlight 3.  Has anyone successfully localized a Prism 2 WPF app with several modules?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/Jinjinov/wpf-localization-multiple-resource-resx-one-language

Answer (score 2):

I'm solved the same problem by having a static LocalizationManager that is reachable from XAML by a custom markupextension, and that works very well.

Take a look at http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html for an example!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You have a lot of options and the gamut of them can be found in this excellent article on CodePlex:
 http://wpflocalization.codeplex.com/

There is very little that is specific to Prism regarding localization.

Comment: Thanks; I decided to use a purely WFP option for now, as stipulated in the doc you reference, but will have to come up with a way that will work for both WPF and Silverlight eventually.